# How to set value of one text area to be the value of another in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, widget

Basically, I'm building a little widget for a site, and I need to set the value of one text area to be another. My current code for changing the value is

```
$('#make').click(function ()    {
$("#widg").attr("value", "test");
});
```

Where I need to set the value of `#widg` to be the value of another input field on the screen, that the user sets the value, when `#make` is clicked. Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#widg').val( $('#some_other_field').val() );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $('selector').val(); for global use - it will work also for text area